# Header not displayed correctly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I just figured out that in my website botlane.net the header is not displayed correctly in Firefox.

Display in Chrome: (Correct behavior) (Also in Internet Explorer)

http://gyazo.com/b76f64331a59eb60e9fc4ade66d76fbb

Display in Firefox: (Wrong behavior)

http://gyazo.com/943e97e3762bf6b85e9d0b5e1c8a2ad0

I managed to recreate the problem in a JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/e8ry9art/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headWrap">
        <a href="/rankings">
            <div id="navi1">
                <span >RANKINGS</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="/">
            <span class="helper"></span><img id="logo" src="http://botlane.net/assets/images/logo3.png" alt="Logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="/legal">
            <div id="navi2">
                <span>LEGAL INFORMATION</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="fulldash"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

div#headWrap {
    width: 1224px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div#navi1 {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

div#navi1:hover {
    color: #FFAD19;
}

div#navi2 {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

div#navi2:hover {
    color: #14CC67;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: First comment: <div> isn't valid inside <a>

Comment: Second comment: You are setting  white-space: nowrap; to all elements inside div#headWrap

Comment: @LuisP.A. `div` inside `a` is valid since HTML5, which he is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing with these styles:

```
div#headWrap {
    width: 1224px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

div#navi1 {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}

div#navi2 {
    float:right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}
```

The above styles work because of the removal of `white-space: nowrap`. The nowrap property is intended to keep text from wrapping to the next line, and can conflict with `text-align: center` since the parent reference for centering is handled differently by firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this base on my comments:

```css
div#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

div#headWrap {
    width: 1224px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

div#navi1 {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
       white-space: nowrap;
}

div#navi1:hover {
    color: #FFAD19;
}

div#navi2 {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div#navi2:hover {
    color: #14CC67;
}

.vmiddle {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
        <div id="header">
            <div id="headWrap">
                
                    <div id="navi1">
                        <a href="/rankings">RANKINGS </a>
                    </div>
               
             
                    <span class="helper"></span>   <a href="/"><img id="logo" src="http://botlane.net/assets/images/logo3.png" alt="Logo" />
                </a>
                
                    <div id="navi2">
                        <a href="/legal">LEGAL INFORMATION  </a>
                    </div>
              
            </div>
            <div id="fulldash"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here and I think Chrome and whatever browser is displaying this as intended by you is just a little bit more forgiving.

First, when using the CSS id selector (e.g. `div#navi2`) you don't need to prepend the tag name of the element you're targeting. `#navi2` is specific enough and everything else is just clutter.

Second, why those extra `div`s inside the `a` elements? You can spare those and directly work with the link elements. They are just as fine.

Third, you're applying your layout code (`float`) to elements that are further down the DOM hierarchy than the one *layer* you're actually targeting. You're trying to sort things out in `#headWrap` and should therefor work with its direct children. But instead you're skipping the `a` elements completely and apply your code to the `div`s. While this isn't wrong per se, in general this means trouble.

Fourth, floated elements (like your links) should come before the element that is being floated. Just a tip to avoid headaches.

I forked your Fiddle with an improved version: http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/Lsrhjnby/

Comment: You are right that the code is very messy. I initially wanted to have the text also vertically centered, thats why the divs. One thing, writing the div before the # is not a bad thing. Because then you could have f.ex. an div element and an p element with the same id put still be able to reference them. Also it makes the css a little bit more readable when you always know which element type is being styled. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: IDs should be unique in a document. Though I do understand your intention. Also, skipping the tag name makes your style less dependent on what you actually have in the DOM and you need to care less if that `div#headerWrap` might become a `<header>` or whatever in the future.